# How to find all sections of a wikipedia page and display them all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api, wikimedia

A wikipedia page is divided by section, therefore If i use the API and say`section=0`, I will read the text within this section. but a page may have many section, how do I loop all of them to load them all?

[MediaWiki Docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext)

> **Here I get `section=0 only`**

[JSFiddle playground here](https://jsfiddle.net/kgyc8to4/37/)

HTML

```
<button id="wiki" data-subject="Paris">Wikipedia</button>

<output id="results">
 <ul>
 </ul>
</output>
```

JS

```
    $("ul").on("click", "a", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("#wiki").one('click', function(e) {
      var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
      $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
          srsearch: articleName,
          action: "query",
          list: "search",
          format: "json"
      }, function(data) {
          $("#results ul").empty();
          $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();
          $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append("<div><a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "</div");
            var myLink = $("#results a").attr("href");
            $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
          });
          $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
              $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&callback=?", {
                  page: e.relatedTarget.textContent
              }, function(data) {
                var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
                var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
                blurb.find('a').each(function() { 
                  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); 
                });
                blurb.find('sup').remove();
                blurb.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
                $(".modal-header .modal-title").html(articleName);
                $(".modal-header .modal-title").promise().done(function(){
                    $(".modal-title").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
                });
                $(".modal-body").html($(blurb).find("p"));
                $(".modal-body").promise().done(function(){
                    $(".modal-body").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
                                });
              });
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Link to a wikipedia which asks not to crawl? The dumps are big, using the api is possible. This service for example does it http://wdq.wmflabs.org/. yet how do I read alla sections?

Comment: I'm not really crawling anyway, I am using their api

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Please_do_not_use_a_web_crawler

Comment: Well unless you can somehow access the webpage on the server without it going over the internet then yes you are downloading. Your downloading this page everytime you view it?!

Comment: Ok good to know, I will eventually make a dump. not aggressing anything for now. However of your correct info, the question remains. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @Liam yeah I am not caching. Anyway its a small demo, we've already discussed between us in regards of the eventual dumping. While for the question in regards, I have just provided my own answer. Thanks

Comment: @Liam btw the dumps are really old, 2008. Any idea why or where are the latest? https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

Comment: Try this link instead, they should have an up to date one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing `section=0` will do:

```
$.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=text&callback=?", {...
```